# Character encoding Mac vs. Windows

Tags: windows, macos, encoding, character

A friend has a text file on his Mac that contains the following line

```
Akamai's profits
```

When I open the same file on Windows, it reads

```
AkamaiÕs profits
```

Does anyone have a guess which encoding is being used here or where else this difference may stem from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman).

Mac OS Roman has `’` at character position 0xD5, and [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (and [Windows CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) have `Õ` at that position.